# How to rename migrations table in entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like rename the migrations table from `dbo.__MigrationHistory` to `SYSTEM.MigrationsHistory`. How can I do it?

I need inherit from `IdentityDbContext` not from `HistoryContext`for this reason I can't use the code: `modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "MigrationHistory", schemaName: "SYSTEM")`

I attach the code that I am using:

```cs
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // ACCOUNT
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable(tableName: "Users", schemaName: "ACCOUNT");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable(tableName: "Roles", schemaName: "ACCOUNT");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().ToTable(tableName: "UserLogins", schemaName: "ACCOUNT");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable(tableName: "UserRoles", schemaName: "ACCOUNT");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserClaim>().ToTable(tableName: "UserClaims", schemaName: "ACCOUNT");

            // SYSTEM
            // modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "MigrationHistory", schemaName: "SYSTEM");
        }


        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: `HistoryContext` derived class is separate from your normal `DbContext` and is used just to customize the migration history table. All this is explained here [Customizing the migrations history table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/history-customization). But note the following paragraph from the link - *Before you start you need to know that you can customize the migrations history table only before you apply the first migration.*. So if you wish to rename an existing history table, according to the docs it's not possible.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your answer. I need inherit from `IdentityDbContext` not from `HistoryContext` for this reason I can't use it (I can not inherit from two classes). There will be another way?

Comment: Did you notice the word **separate**?  e.g. `class CustomHistoryContext : HistoryContext { …}` - it has nothing to do with your `ApplicationDbContext`.

Comment: I noticed it but I did not understand it, but I understand it better, I'll do the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps for rename migrations table

1. Create class `MyHistoryContext`:

```cs
    using System.Data.Common;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History;

    namespace CustomizableMigrationsHistoryTableSample
    {
        public class MyHistoryContext : HistoryContext
        {
            public MyHistoryContext(DbConnection dbConnection, string defaultSchema)
                : base(dbConnection, defaultSchema)
            {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().ToTable(tableName: "MigrationHistory", schemaName: "SYSTEM");
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Create class `ModelConfiguration`

```cs
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace CustomizableMigrationsHistoryTableSample
    {
        public class ModelConfiguration : DbConfiguration
        {
            public ModelConfiguration()
            {
                this.SetHistoryContext("System.Data.SqlClient",
                    (connection, defaultSchema) => new MyHistoryContext(connection, defaultSchema));
            }
        }
    }
```

3. If you have existing migrations, you will need to delete migrations and database for execute the next commands:

For create `migrations` folder and `configuration` class:

```sh
enable-migrations
```

For add migration `first_migration`

```sh
add-migration <migration_name>
```

For apply migration(s) in data base

```sh
update-database
```

Credits: [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev)

> Before you start you need to know that you can customize the migrations history table only before you apply the first migration..

Detailed information: 
[Customizing the migrations history table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/history-customization)

Comment: This is no more relevant for a new EntityFramework (> version 6). Now you have to use it like this: `var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CentralToolsMigrationsDbContext>().UseOracle(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"), x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("EFMIGRATIONSHISTORY__", MyDbSchema))`